# DOM element that holds custom information

Tags: javascript, attributes, element

I have a DOM element that shows time:

```
<div id="time"></div>
```

Time showing function is written in JavaScript.
But I also need to hold additional information about this element, for example time pattern.
I mean if I call a function like `getElementById` (just an example), I want to know this element additional attributes (in my case time pattern)
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data` attributes. They're meant to store data:

```
<div id="time" data-pattern="test"></div>
```

And some test JavaScript:

```
​var time = document.getElementById('time');

console.log(time.getAttribute('data-pattern')​​​​);​
```

If you're using jQuery, you can use the `.data()` method to extract the value and automatically convert common data types:

```
$('#time').data('pattern');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UPufH/**

Comment: If you're going to suggest data attributes, why not also describe the HTML5 way to retrieve the data? `time.dataset.pattern` Older browsers will still need `getAttribute()` of course, but it's still good to know the proper HTML5 syntax.

Comment: ...oh, and you forget the demo in your demo. ;-)

Comment: @user1689607: Thanks, I'm not sure what happened there. I didn't suggest `dataset` because it doesn't work at all in IE. There's probably a polyfill somewhere.